# Error: Use drupal_write_record() to update only field

Tags: 7, database

I created a custom module for Drupal 7. I have a custom form:

```
$query = db_select( 'taxonomy_term_data', 't' )
    ->condition( 't.vid', '5')
    ->fields('t', array('tid'))
    ->fields('t', array('name'));
$result = $query->execute();
foreach($result as $row){
  $phong_ban[$row->tid] = $row->name;
}

$default_phong_ban[] = '';
if(isset($node->field_phong_ban['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->tid)){
  $default_phong_ban = $node->field_phong_ban['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->tid;
  $form['phong_ban_is_new'] = array(
    '#type' =>'hidden',
    '#value' => 1,
  );
}
$form['phong_ban'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Lựa chọn phòng ban'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#options' => $phong_ban,
    '#default_value' => $default_phong_ban,
    '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
            'select[name="state"]' => array('value' => 'chuyen_xuong_phong_xu_ly'),
        ),
    ),
    '#required' => true,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Thực hiện'),
  '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'edit-submit-form-moderation',
  ),
);
```

And a form submission handler.

```
    $values = array(
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => 'danh_gia_tac_dong_moi_truong',
      'entity_id' => $node->nid,
      'revision_id' => $node->vid,
      'language' => 'und',
      'delta' => 0,
      'field_phong_ban_tid' => $form_state['values']['phong_ban'],
  );
    drupal_write_record('field_data_field_phong_ban', $values, 'entity_type');
    drupal_write_record('field_revision_field_phong_ban', $values, 'entity_type');
```

The code causes the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should not update the fields directly with sql queries. You can use following function (as Shubham said in the comment) :

[field_attach_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7)

> Save field data for an existing entity.
>
> When calling this function
> outside an entity save operation be sure to clear caches for the
> entity:
>
> entity_get_controller($entity_type)->resetCache(array($entity_id))

What you simply need to do is :

```
$node = node_load($nid); // Load the node
$node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'Update value'; // Update value
field_attach_update('node', $node); // Update field vlaue
entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($node->nid)); // clear entity cache
```